# Can I use CKEditor in my iOS application?

Tags: ios, ckeditor

Well I've searched for the answer to this, and nothing seems to provide a clear solution... so here goes...

We have a web application that we are re-creating in iOS.  Parts of the application utilize CKEditor to edit contents of templates (for sending emails, etc.).

Is there a way to use CKEditor within the iOS app, or is there something similar that anyone can recommend that provides the same base functionality?

Thanks, to all, in advance...

EDIT: (Thanks to the comment by @Dekel)

It should be noted that the editor needs to work whether the device is online or offline.  So a true WebView item won't work (I believe - could be wrong).

Comment: ckeditor needs a browser to run, so if you can run a browser within your iOS application (a browser component) - you can run this code inside that browser.

Comment: I just tried CKEditor in a test app, it does not even display :(

Checked and rechecked paths, they are all correct.

Comment: Have you tried this?  https://github.com/insanoid/iOS-HTMLTextEditor

Comment: Interesting @Necreaux  Thanks for that tip.